# Pass data between uiview

Tags: xcode, uiview

I have a problem passing data between view. I can pass my NSMutableArray easily using :

---

```
DetailViewController *detailNote = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailNote"];

 detailNote.ArrayItem = [allAnotacionsEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailNote animated:YES];
```

---

but I want to pass additional NSMutableArray to the view and I don´t know how to do it.

Please anyone can help me ?

Comment: You seriously have to start accepting answers. 
Look though your questions and see if anyone has posted a helpful answer. They took the time to write it, you just have to take 3 seconds to click the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new property in the `DetailViewController` Class
Add this to the .h file.

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *yourPropertyName;
```

Then you can set the array like this:

```
detailNote.yourPropertyName = [NSMutableArray array];
```